# C++ Fuzzy Logic loop increments after first input

Tags: c++, fuzzy-logic

I wrote my first Fuzzy Logic program and the first input does its job perfectly by outputting the correct voltage value. The word Voltage is strictly a place holder. It matches my math exactly. Any value afterwards, increases the final output and NEVER works again until I reset the program, upon which, it does the same thing.

I'll try to simplify my code as much as possible.

```
int main()
{
int InputDistance;
double BetweenDistance1;
double BetweenDistance2;
double DoM1;
double DoM2;
double OutputComponent1;
double OutputComponent2;
double CrispOutput;
bool NN = false;
bool N = false;
bool Z = false;
const double NNVolt (0);
const double NVolt (2.25);
const double ZVolt (4.5);
for(;;)
{
        cout <<  "What is the distance?" << endl << endl;
        cin >> InputDistance;
        cout << endl;
        if(InputDistance > 0 && InputDistance <= 5)
        {
            BetweenDistance1 = InputDistance - 0;
            BetweenDistance2 = 5 - InputDistance;
            NN = true;
            N = true;
        }
        if(InputDistance > 5 && InputDistance <= 10)
        {
            BetweenDistance1 = InputDistance - 5;
            BetweenDistance2 = 10 - InputDistance;
            NN = true;
            N = true;
        }
        if(InputDistance > 10 && InputDistance <= 15)
        {
            BetweenDistance1 = InputDistance - 10;
            BetweenDistance2 = 15 - InputDistance;
            N = true;
            Z = true;
        }
        if(InputDistance > 15 && InputDistance <= 20)
        {
            BetweenDistance1 = InputDistance - 15;
            BetweenDistance2 = 20 - InputDistance;
            N = true;
            Z = true;
        }

        DoM1 = BetweenDistance1 / 5;
        DoM2 = BetweenDistance2 / 5;

        if(NN == true && N == true)
        {
            OutputComponent1 = NNVolt * DoM1;
            OutputComponent2 = NVolt * DoM2;
        }
        if(N == true && Z == true)
        {
            OutputComponent1 = NVolt * DoM1;
            OutputComponent2 = ZVolt * DoM2;
        }
        CrispOutput = OutputComponent1 + OutputComponent2;

        cout << "Voltage = " << CrispOutput << endl << endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

What is causing the values to increment every time I input a new distance value? I can't see it.

Comment: You do not reset NN, N and Z. Nor do you initialize any of the other variables, you really should...

Comment: Maybe with a bit more patience I could find out myself, but what is the exact expected and resulting output of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never resetting your `bool`s.

```
bool NN = false;
bool N = false;
bool Z = false;
```

Should be at that start of your for loop so that they are reset every time it loops.

As a rule of thumb any variable that you will use in a loop should be declared in the loop unless you need to access it outside the scope of the loop.

Comment: I'm running some tests now.

Comment: Ok! My problem seems to be solved! I've now run into some problems that require my double checking of the code itself but the Primary problem seems to be solved. Nothing is increasing in value. Thank you!

Comment: @Hennry If `CrispOutput` should be increasing in value every iteration then it should be `CrispOutput += OutputComponent1 + OutputComponent2;`.  The `+=` means add this to the previous value and assign.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize all your variables, because even though your compiler will initialize them to `null, "", preppended "\0", 0, 0.0, 0.0f` it's can be taken to be compiled under a different compiler that doesn't follow such a standard, or compiling with flags that initialize using different stuff.

```
int main()
{
    int InputDistance = 0;
    double BetweenDistance1 = 0.0;
    double BetweenDistance2 = 0.0;
    double DoM1 = 0.0;
    double DoM2 = 0.0;
    double OutputComponent1 = 0.0;
    double OutputComponent2 = 0.0;
    double CrispOutput = 0.0;
    bool NN = false;
    bool N = false;
    bool Z = false;
    const double NNVolt (0);
    const double NVolt (2.25);
    const double ZVolt (4.5);
```

And you should re-initialize at the beginning of the loop to make sure you don't end up using data from previous iterations.

```
    for(;;)
    {
            //----------- init ------------
            InputDistance = 0;
            BetweenDistance1 = 0.0;
            BetweenDistance2 = 0.0;
            DoM1 = 0.0;
            DoM2 = 0.0;
            OutputComponent1 = 0.0;
            OutputComponent2 = 0.0;
            CrispOutput = 0.0;
            NN = false;
            N = false;
            Z = false;
            //-----------------------------

            cout <<  "What is the distance?" << endl << endl;
            cin >> InputDistance;
            cout << endl;

            ..            

        }

        return (0);
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee a compiler will default initialize a variable unless it has a default constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's in case of class members, but I was refering to initial value of local variables as in `void main(..) { int InputDistance;` for example, some envoirnments set it to `0`, some `undefined`, or a value previously written in that memory.